# filename sequence extraction python

Tags: python-2.7

I have to identify and isolate a number sequence from the file names in a folder of files, and optionally, identify non-continuous sequences.  The files are .dpx files.  There is almost no file naming structure except that somewhere in the filename is a sequence number, and an extention of '.dpx'.  There is a wonderful module called PySeq that can do all of the hard work, except it just bombs with a directory of thousands and sometimes hundreds of thousands of files.  "Argument list too large".  Has anyone had experience working with sequence number isolation and dpx files in particular?  Each file can be up to 100MB in size.  I am working on a CentOS box using Python2.7.

```
File names might be something like:<br/>
test00_take1_00001.dpx<br/>
test00_take1_00002.dpx<br/>
another_take_ver1-0001_3.dpx<br/>
another_take_ver1-0002_3.dpx<br/>
```

(Two continuous sequences)

Comment: What is your code that produces the error?

Answer (score 1):

This should do exactly what you're looking for. It will create a dict of dicts containing start and end of strings and putting the full string in a list.

It will then join all of the lists into a single list (You might as well skip on this part and turn it into a generator of lists for higher efficiency regarding memory)

```
from collections import defaultdict

input_list = [
    "test00_take1_00001.dpx",
    "test00_take1_00002.dpx",
    "another_take_ver1-0001_3.dpx",
    "another_take_ver1-0002_3.dpx"]

results_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
matches = (re.match(r"(.*?[\W_])\d+([\W_].*)", item) for item in input_list)
for match in matches:
    results_dict[match.group(1)][match.group(2)].append(match.group(0))

results_list = [d2 for d1 in results_dict.values() for d2 in d1.values()]

>>> results_list
[['another_take_ver1-0001_3.dpx', 'another_take_ver1-0002_3.dpx'], ['test00_take
1_00001.dpx', 'test00_take1_00002.dpx']]
```

Comment: Thank you Bharel!! This works great. I don't know anything about generators, so this is a great incentive. :)  Thanks again very much.

Comment: Hi @tinker242 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm still a little new here. Your answer absolutely did solve my problem.  :)

Comment: @tinker242 no problem mate, any time. :-)